# How to counteract Java "No Line Found" error?

Tags: java

I put scan.nextLine() twice in order to counteract my program from completing before finishing compiling everything after scan.nextLine(). Doing this results in this error:

> Runtime Error: Runtime ErrorException in thread "main"
>   java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found   at
>   java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)     at
>   GFG.main(File.java:24)

This is because I have added an extra scan.nextLine() in order to counteract the problem above (I am only scanning for one thing). Since I am scanning twice, my program when looped for the second time prompts the user twice and only parses the second input.

Needed to add another scan.nextLine() in order to counteract program from ending before parsing everything after scan.nextLine() (this was the solution to another post regarding a similar issue).

```
public class DT
{
   public static void main (String [] args)
   {

   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.println("Enter # of test cases: ");

   int t = scan.nextInt();

   if (t >= 1 && t<= 100)
   {

   System.out.println("Enter values ");

   for ( int j = 0; j < t; j++)
   {

   scan.nextLine();
   String input = scan.nextLine(); //When you enter a second value, code is still scanning, prompts again

   StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(input);

      for (int i = 1; st1.hasMoreTokens(); i++)
      {

      String val1 = st1.nextToken();
      int num1 = Integer.parseInt(val1);
      String temp = st1.nextToken();
      String temp2 = st1.nextToken();
      float num2 = Float.parseFloat(temp2);
      System.out.println(num1 + " " + temp + " " + num2);

      }
   }
   }
   }   
   }
```

Comment: Can you paste your complete code & sample output?

Comment: Yes, I will do so.

Comment: Thank you! What is your use case? Use of StringTokenizer class is generally discouraged as it is a legacy class and it is there in java package just for compatibility. If you can tell your use case, I may suggest an alternative.

Comment: BTW, the java.util.NoSuchElementException is coming because you seems to be trying to get next token after num1. Since there is no further token, you are getting the exception.

Comment: The posted class is called `DT`. However the error message is about `GFG` class.

Comment: I am using an online compiler in order to test the code for submission (GeeksforGeeks).

Comment: Akash, I am using the tokenizer class in order to find each individual word in a user's input. Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Instead of StringTokenizer, it can be easier to use the String.split method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to call `nextLine()` directly after the call to `nextInt()`, and not inside a loop. This is because when you enter an int, you also press the Enter key so there is a line terminator. So you need to call `nextLine()` after `nextInt()` to read and remove the line terminator from the input buffer. Inside the loop you are already calling `nextLine()` so don't call it again. Here's the code change:

```
System.out.print("Enter # of test cases: ");

int t = scan.nextInt();
scan.nextLine();

if (t >= 1 && t<= 100)
{
    System.out.println("Enter values:");

    for (int j = 0; j < t; j++)
    {
        String input = scan.nextLine();
```

Notice there's only one call to `nextLine()` inside the loop.